# Angular Material md-select not binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Hello all thanks for reading, i'm having a issue with Angular Material md-select

it doesn't bind with my model. i'm using it to make a form to update data of this model.

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon md-block" flex ng-controller="ProveedorController" data-ng-init="listaProveedores()">
<label>Proveedor</label>
<md-select ng-model="detalle.proveedor" required name="proveedores">
    <md-option ng-value="proveedor" ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores">{{proveedor.nombreProveedor}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

i've tried to use `ng-selected` but it bind another object that doesn't fit with the original of the model.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, after a good sleep and hours of searching i've found the solution of this.

to keep track of the objects i need to add a property on my md-select

in this case something similar to this: `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"`

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon md-block" flex ng-controller="ProveedorController" data-ng-init="listaProveedores()">
    <label>Proveedor</label>
    <md-select ng-model="detalle.proveedor" required name="proveedores" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.idProveedor'}">
        <md-option ng-value="proveedor" ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores">{{proveedor.nombreProveedor}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

now all my models are display fine. Thank you for reading and sorry if i waste your time.

Comment: You can also do it like this: "`ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores track by proveedor.idProveedor"`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: what if you dont have an id and you want to track with 2 properties? what is the way to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this first hand and attempted different solutions to no avail.  The ultimate fix was using a controller instance variable instead of $scope to hold the ng-model value.

Instead of referencing `$scope.somemodel`to retrieve the updated model value, use `this.somemodel`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qNaYGG)

Markup

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ProveedorController">
  <md-input-container class="md-icon md-block" flex data-ng-init="listaProveedores()">
    <label>Proveedor</label>
    <md-select ng-model="detalle.proveedor" required name="proveedores">
      <md-option ng-value="proveedor.nombreProveedor" ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores">
        {{proveedor.nombreProveedor}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <br>
  Proveedor: {{detalle.proveedor}}
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('ProveedorController', function($scope) {
  $scope.proveedores = [
    {nombreProveedor: "Daffy"},
    {nombreProveedor: "Mickey"},
    {nombreProveedor: "Goofy"}];
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this only add a dependency for icons, still not resolving my problem with binding. i already can create objects with this select
(this is a CRUD of products), but it doesn't display the value when i need to make a update of this object (Product), something is wrong and initialize wrong